# Is it possible to use feeds with lazy lists?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, raku

This works:

```
bastille% perl6 -e 'my @squares = (1...*).map({ $_ ** 2 }); say @squares[0..^10].join: ", "'
1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100
```

However this doesn't:

```
bastille% perl6 -e 'my @squares <== map { $_ ** 2 } <== 1...*; say @squares[0..^10].join: ", "'
Cannot push a lazy list onto a Array
  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

Why does this throw? Is there a way that lazy lists can be used with feeds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The feed operator `<==` appends elements to the array.

```perl6
my @s <== ^3; 
@s <== <a>..<c>; 
say @s
```

```
[0 1 2 a b c]
```

So

```perl6
my @squares <== map { $_ ** 2 } <== 1...*;
```

works similarly as

```perl6
my @squares.append: map  * ** 2, 1..*;
```

You can use the *item assignment operator* `=` with brackets

```perl6
my @squares = ( map { $_ ** 2 } <== 1..* );
```

or the next little hack

```perl6
[=] my @squares <== map { $_ ** 2 } <== 1..*;
```

Comment: The `my @squares = ( ... );` solution seems like a nice, clean, simple-to-explain idiomatic solution. The other one looks insane... :)

Comment: FWIW, I don't believe this behaviour of feed operators is actually correct.  See https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2899